# wordpress post thumbnail resizing issue

Tags: wordpress, post, slider, thumbnails

I am trying to resize post thumbnail image in custom post loop but is taking the original image size.

`

```
             <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides"> 


                    <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sliders', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
              <?php while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?>
                    <div class="flex-caption">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-theme">Learn More</a>
                    </div>

                  </li>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>
               </ul>
            </div>
<!-- end slider -->
        </div>`
```

In the function.php in make this hard cropping features of the image--

```
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 1024, 360, true );
```

Its not displaying the hard cropping size of the images.

Please help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make the custom crop after the images had already been uploaded? If so, you'll need to regenerate the images.

Comment: yes  I re-uploaded new image but not working. It shows original size of the slide image. It may be problem with css but I can not identify the bug.

Comment: Hey man!! Now its working. I just re-upload another new image and it taking the hard cropping. Thanks for your suggestion.